# Can't fix an error occuring while using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I just got started with hibernate so dont know what to do, here's the error log I did't knew what part to post so I ended up posting the whole error log :

```
Dec 01, 2018 7:07:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Dec 01, 2018 7:07:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 01, 2018 7:07:52 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Dec 01, 2018 7:07:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at config.DbConfig.<init>(DbConfig.java:16)
    at model.dao.ProductDAO.<init>(ProductDAO.java:17)
    at com.vinodh.ProjectBE.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.h2.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.h2.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
    ... 28 more

and here's the code :
```

Hibernate Util file

```
package config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;

import model.entity.Product;

public class HibernateUtil {
       private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
       private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          if (sessionFactory == null) {
             try {

                // Create registry builder
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "org.h2.Driver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ShoppingDB");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "Aziz");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "*Aziz007");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

                // Apply settings
                registryBuilder.applySettings(settings);

                // Create registry
                registry = registryBuilder.build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                sources.addAnnotatedClass(Product.class);
                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();


                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();


             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                   StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
             }
          }
          return sessionFactory;
       }

       public static void shutdown() {
          if (registry != null) {
             StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
          }
       }
}
```

DB config file :

```
package config;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DbConfig {

    private Configuration cfg;
    private SessionFactory sf;
    private Session sess;

    public DbConfig()
    {
        cfg = new Configuration();
        sf = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public Session getSess()
    {
        sess = sf.openSession();
        return sess;
    }


}
```

should I change hibernate.cfg.xml in cfg config as I'm not using an xml file here I've Integrated that in my Util file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem from the stacktrace:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.h2.Driver

This is specified as the driver setting explicitly set in your code.

You have to provide the database driver in your class path or specify one that exists.

Answer (score 0):

> You should add H2 jdbc driver jar file inside your classpath